# Match a word without space to match with a text with space in elasticsearch

Tags: php, elasticsearch, elasticsearch-query, elasticsearch-analyzers

The question title is a bit misleading but I didn't know how to put it properly but here is my scenario

I have a word **Water wipes** (see the space in between) in the title of a product record in my elastic search. Now I need to match it for **waterwipes**. since there is no space in between I am getting zero results for the query *waterwipes*. The following is the must match query in the Elastic search (I am using PHP here)

```
 $mustConditions = [
   [
      "nested" => [
          "path"  => "name",
          "query" => [
             "multi_match" => [
                "query"            => (string)$query,
                "fields"           => ['name.en^3', 'name.ar^3'],
                "zero_terms_query" => "all",
                "fuzziness"        => "auto",
                "operator"         => "AND",
             ],
          ],   
        ],
      ],
   ];
```

And the analyzer for the field is 'english'. How do I match for words like *Water Wipes* for *waterwipes*

Answer (score 1):

You need to erase the whitespace from the title of your product and index it and later on you can query on that word.

Please see the Index setting for removing the whitespace:{

```
    "settings": {
        "analysis": {
            "analyzer": {
                "my_analyzer": {
                    "tokenizer": "standard",
                    "char_filter": [
                        "replace_whitespace"
                    ]
                }
            },
            "char_filter": {
                "replace_whitespace": {
                    "type": "mapping",
                    "mappings": [
                        "\\u0020=>"
                    ]
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

After this, you can use [ES analyze API](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/indices-analyze.html) to confirm its generating token which would match your search query tokens.

POST _analyze

```
{
    "text": "Water wipes",
    "analyzer" : "my_analyzer"
}

{
    "tokens": [
        {
            "token": "Waterwipes", --> Notice whitespace is removed
            "start_offset": 0,
            "end_offset": 7,
            "type": "<ALPHANUM>",
            "position": 0
        }
    ]
}
```

Suggestions: You should store these whitespace removed tokens in another field of `title` like `titlewospaces` and apply above custom analyzer on it and search on both the fields to get better results. **Also, you should check [Explain API](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/search-explain.html) to see what tokens your query generating and how it matches with indexed tokens.**

Comment: Thank you for your answer, I will test this out and I have one question. If I create the custom analyzer and apply it on the field, will it return results for *water wipes* ? (with space?). So both *waterwipes* and *water wipes* will work?

Comment: Also the title for the products are more like this *Water Wipes - Mega Value Pack - 12 x 60s Wipes* instead of simple *water wipes*. I guess your version removes all the whitespaces in the text ?

Comment: @Shobi , yes it will remove white space from all the places

Comment: Hey, Sorry for the late reply. Actually What I ended up doing is that include the description in the index, and stuff *waterwipes* in the description so that elastic would include that result as well. Your answer was super helpful and I learned about the explain API (Thank you).

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/208916/discussion-between-opster-elasticsearch-ninja-and-shobi).

Comment: I did upvote, but this is not an answer which can be accepted as correct answer.